# What is the difference between Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.8

I'm not clear on the differences between the "current" version of Ruby (1.8) and the "new" version (1.9). Is there an "easy" or a "simple" explanation of the differences and why it is so different?

Comment: I assume you mean Ruby 1.8.6 - Ruby 1.8.7 has a lot of library constructs from 1.9.

Comment: Any more I consider the 1.8 versions the "old" versions, and 1.9.2+ the "current" ones. I only use 1.8.7 for compatibility checks but develop in 1.9.2.

Comment: @Telemachus: The link's broken.

Comment: @Telemachus, Andrew Grimm -- this archive.org link works -- http://web.archive.org/web/20090423003136/http://eigenclass.org/hiki.rb?Changes+in+Ruby+1.9

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Sam Ruby has a [cool slideshow that outline the differences](http://slideshow.rubyforge.org/ruby19.html).

In the interest of bringing this information inline for easier reference, and in case the link goes dead in the abstract future, here's an overview of Sam's slides. The slideshow is less overwhelming to review, but having it all laid out in a list like this is also helpful.

## Ruby 1.9 - Major Features

- Performance
- Threads/Fibers
- Encoding/Unicode
- gems is (mostly) built-in now
- if statements do not introduce scope in Ruby.

## What's changed?

### Single character strings.

Ruby 1.9

```
irb(main):001:0> ?c
=> "c"
```

Ruby 1.8.6

```
irb(main):001:0> ?c
=> 99
```

---

### String index.

Ruby 1.9

```
irb(main):001:0> "cat"[1]
=> "a"
```

Ruby 1.8.6

```
irb(main):001:0> "cat"[1]
=> 97
```

---

### {"a","b"} No Longer Supported

Ruby 1.9

```
irb(main):002:0> {1,2}
SyntaxError: (irb):2: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tASSOC
```

Ruby 1.8.6

```
irb(main):001:0> {1,2}
=> {1=>2}
```

**Action:** Convert to {1 => 2}

---

### `Array.to_s` Now Contains Punctuation

Ruby 1.9

```
irb(main):001:0> [1,2,3].to_s
=> "[1, 2, 3]"
```

Ruby 1.8.6

```
irb(main):001:0> [1,2,3].to_s
=> "123"
```

**Action:** Use .join instead

---

### Colon No Longer Valid In When Statements

Ruby 1.9

```
irb(main):001:0> case 'a'; when /\w/: puts 'word'; end
SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected ':',
expecting keyword_then or ',' or ';' or '\n'
```

Ruby 1.8.6

```
irb(main):001:0> case 'a'; when /\w/: puts 'word'; end
word
```

**Action:** Use semicolon, then, or newline

---

### Block Variables Now Shadow Local Variables

Ruby 1.9

```
irb(main):001:0> i=0; [1,2,3].each {|i|}; i
=> 0
irb(main):002:0> i=0; for i in [1,2,3]; end; i
=> 3
```

Ruby 1.8.6

```
irb(main):001:0> i=0; [1,2,3].each {|i|}; i
=> 3
```

---

### `Hash.index` Deprecated

Ruby 1.9

```
irb(main):001:0> {1=>2}.index(2)
(irb):18: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
=> 1
irb(main):002:0> {1=>2}.key(2)
=> 1
```

Ruby 1.8.6

```
irb(main):001:0> {1=>2}.index(2)
=> 1
```

**Action:** Use Hash.key

---

### `Fixnum.to_sym` Now Gone

Ruby 1.9

```
irb(main):001:0> 5.to_sym
NoMethodError: undefined method 'to_sym' for 5:Fixnum
```

Ruby 1.8.6

```
irb(main):001:0> 5.to_sym
=> nil
```

(Cont'd) Ruby 1.9

```
# Find an argument value by name or index.
def [](index)
  lookup(index.to_sym)
end
```

svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/trunk/lib/rake.rb

---

### Hash Keys Now Unordered

Ruby 1.9

```
irb(main):001:0> {:a=>"a", :c=>"c", :b=>"b"}
=> {:a=>"a", :c=>"c", :b=>"b"}
```

Ruby 1.8.6

```
irb(main):001:0> {:a=>"a", :c=>"c", :b=>"b"}
=> {:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>"c"}
```

Order is insertion order

---

### Stricter Unicode Regular Expressions

Ruby 1.9

```
irb(main):001:0> /\x80/u
SyntaxError: (irb):2: invalid multibyte escape: /\x80/
```

Ruby 1.8.6

```
irb(main):001:0> /\x80/u
=> /\x80/u
```

---

### `tr` and `Regexp` Now Understand Unicode

Ruby 1.9

```
unicode(string).tr(CP1252_DIFFERENCES, UNICODE_EQUIVALENT).
  gsub(INVALID_XML_CHAR, REPLACEMENT_CHAR).
  gsub(XML_PREDEFINED) {|c| PREDEFINED[c.ord]}
```

---

### `pack` and `unpack`

Ruby 1.8.6

```
def xchr(escape=true)
  n = XChar::CP1252[self] || self
  case n when *XChar::VALID
    XChar::PREDEFINED[n] or 
      (n>128 ? n.chr : (escape ? "&##{n};" : [n].pack('U*')))
  else
    Builder::XChar::REPLACEMENT_CHAR
  end
end
unpack('U*').map {|n| n.xchr(escape)}.join
```

---

### `BasicObject` More Brutal Than `BlankSlate`

Ruby 1.9

```
irb(main):001:0> class C < BasicObject; def f; Math::PI; end; end; C.new.f
NameError: uninitialized constant C::Math
```

Ruby 1.8.6

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'blankslate'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> class C < BlankSlate; def f; Math::PI; end; end; C.new.f
=> 3.14159265358979
```

**Action:** Use ::Math::PI

---

### Delegation Changes

Ruby 1.9

```
irb(main):002:0> class C < SimpleDelegator; end
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> C.new('').class
=> String
```

Ruby 1.8.6

```
irb(main):002:0> class C < SimpleDelegator; end
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> C.new('').class
=> C
irb(main):004:0>
```

[Defect 17700](http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=17700&group_id=426&atid=1698)

---

### Use of $KCODE Produces Warnings

Ruby 1.9

```
irb(main):004:1> $KCODE = 'UTF8'
(irb):4: warning: variable $KCODE is no longer effective; ignored
=> "UTF8"
```

Ruby 1.8.6

```
irb(main):001:0> $KCODE = 'UTF8'
=> "UTF8"
```

---

### `instance_methods` Now an Array of Symbols

Ruby 1.9

```
irb(main):001:0> {}.methods.sort.last
=> :zip
```

Ruby 1.8.6

```
irb(main):001:0> {}.methods.sort.last
=> "zip"
```

**Action:** Replace instance_methods.include? with method_defined?

---

### Source File Encoding

#### Basic

```
# coding: utf-8
```

#### Emacs

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
```

#### Shebang

```
#!/usr/local/rubybook/bin/ruby
# encoding: utf-8
```

---

### Real Threading

- Race Conditions
- Implicit Ordering Assumptions
- Test Code

---

## What's New?

### Alternate Syntax for Symbol as Hash Keys

Ruby 1.9

```
{a: b}

redirect_to action: show
```

Ruby 1.8.6

```
{:a => b}

redirect_to :action => show
```

---

### Block Local Variables

Ruby 1.9

```
[1,2].each {|value; t| t=value*value}
```

---

### Inject Methods

Ruby 1.9

```
[1,2].inject(:+)
```

Ruby 1.8.6

```
[1,2].inject {|a,b| a+b}
```

---

### `to_enum`

Ruby 1.9

```
short_enum = [1, 2, 3].to_enum
long_enum = ('a'..'z').to_enum
loop do
  puts "#{short_enum.next} #{long_enum.next}"
end
```

---

### No block? Enum!

Ruby 1.9

```
e = [1,2,3].each
```

---

### Lambda Shorthand

Ruby 1.9

```
p = -> a,b,c {a+b+c}
puts p.(1,2,3)
puts p[1,2,3]
```

Ruby 1.8.6

```
p = lambda {|a,b,c| a+b+c}
puts p.call(1,2,3)
```

---

### Complex Numbers

Ruby 1.9

```
Complex(3,4) == 3 + 4.im
```

---

### Decimal Is Still Not The Default

Ruby 1.9

```
irb(main):001:0> 1.2-1.1
=> 0.0999999999999999
```

---

### Regex “Properties”

Ruby 1.9

```
/\p{Space}/
```

Ruby 1.8.6

```
/[:space:]/
```

---

### Splat in Middle

Ruby 1.9

```
def foo(first, *middle, last)

(->a, *b, c {p a-c}).(*5.downto(1))
```

---

### Fibers

Ruby 1.9

```
f = Fiber.new do
  a,b = 0,1
  Fiber.yield a
  Fiber.yield b
  loop do
    a,b = b,a+b
    Fiber.yield b
  end
end
10.times {puts f.resume}
```

---

### Break Values

Ruby 1.9

```
match =
   while line = gets
     next if line =~ /^#/
     break line if line.find('ruby')
   end
```

---

### “Nested” Methods

Ruby 1.9

```
def toggle
  def toggle
    "subsequent times"
  end
  "first time"
end
```

---

HTH!

Comment: HTH == "Hope that helps". I had to look that up. Can you point me to an answer you provided, where you didn't hope that it would help?

Comment: Or did you mean Happy to help? Please edit accordingly. Or remove it, if your happiness/hopefulness counts for all your answers. ;-)

Comment: No, I'm going to leave it as-is. As a percentage of the total answer, it's minuscule and either interpretation is fine with me. Thanks.

Comment: According to the link you provided, the change in delegation was a bug and has been fixed.

Comment: What about the inconsistency between "Range.include?" method? Ruby v1.8.7 gives a different result than v1.9

Answer (score 12):

One huge difference would be the move from Matz's interpreter to [YARV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YARV), a bytecode virtual machine that helps significantly with performance.

Answer (score 4):

Many now recommend [The Ruby Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516177) over the Pickaxe - more to the point, it has all the details of the 1.8/1.9 differences.

Comment: I like them both. The Pickaxe book discusses some things more fully but The Ruby Programming Language is good when you want to quickly scan for something. It's closer to a "nutshell" book.

Answer (score 1):

Some more changes:

**Returning a splat singleton array:**

```
def function
  return *[1]
end

a=function
```

- ruby 1.9 : [1]
- ruby 1.8 : 1

**array arguments**

```
def function(array)
  array.each { |v| p v }
end
function "1"
```

- ruby 1.8: "1"
- ruby 1.9: undefined method `each' for "1":String