# What are the major differences between Ruby 1.8.6 and 1.9.1?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574/what-is-the-difference-between-ruby-1-8-and-ruby-1-9)

I have found some differences in interpretation of global and local variables.

Can anyone point me to list of major differences?

Answer (score 3):

These are probably the most important changes:

- Ruby 1.9 changed from being
  interpreted to being
  bytecode-compiled (using the YARV
  VM).
- The String class has been redesigned
  entirely to make it encoding-aware.
- Regular expressions are now
  implemented using the Oniguruma
  engine, rather than the home-made one
  used in ruby 1.8, enabling new
  features like negative look-around.
- The `enumerator` library from stdlib
  has been added to core and most
  `Enumerable` methods have been
  changed to return an `Enumerator`
  when invoked without a block.
- `Symbol#to_proc` has been added.
- There's a new syntax for lambdas,
  `->` which allows default arguments
  and lambdas taking blocks.

There's a more complete list of changes [here](http://eigenclass.org/hiki/Changes+in+Ruby+1.9).

Answer (score 1):

One major point might be that they use a different VM (at least, the 'standard' distributions do, obviously there are a number of options like MacRuby, IronRuby, etc). You might have a look [here](http://eigenclass.org/hiki/Changes+in+Ruby+1.9) for details on all the changes.

Comment: thanks. I still didn't touch mac\iron\jruby - no need. Only moving to RoR