# Ruby Video Tutorials

Tags: ruby, video, jruby

I know nothing about ruby.

Do you know some beginner video tutorials for ruby? And also tutorials for Ruby Enterprise development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some video tutorials on all the basics of the Ruby language over at http://manwithcode.com, but from his last post it seems that the site is probably dead. However the videos are still worth a watch, especially since they're free.

Comment: As someone who is new to Ruby, are these tutorials up to date in a sense of what he is suggesting?

Comment: Yes, they only explain basic ruby constructs. Even though they were done in Ruby 1.8, they are still good. If you want to view the differences in 1.8 and 1.9 see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574/what-is-the-difference-between-ruby-1-8-and-ruby-1-9).

Answer (score 2):

There is a fun tutorial for ruby : [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/)

> Learning Rails for the first time should be fun, and Rails for Zombies allows you to get your feet wet without having to worry about configuration. You'll watch five videos, each followed by exercises where you'll be programming Rails in your browser.

In addition, there a lot of casts about rails on [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/).

Comment: I thought he was talking about Ruby, not about Ruby on Rails.

Comment: So If u found what i mean, aren't u gonna guide me on that?

Answer (score 2):

It's not video, but it's a great resource that won't waste your time, "The Well-Grounded Rubyist Covering Ruby 1.9 David A. Black": http://www.manning.com/black2/

I've worked through the text using a MacBook, rvm, git, textmate, and iTerm, which are all good supporting tools IMHO.

- rvm : https://rvm.io
- git: http://git-scm.com/
- textmate: http://macromates.com/
- iTerm: http://iterm.sourceforge.net/

If you are ultimately aiming to try Rails as well, Michael Hartl's "Ruby on Rails Tutorial"
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ is free on-line and is highly recommended.  This includes a lot of fundamental Ruby teaching.  There are accompanying screencasts that are $$$, but they are well reviewed.

Took me a while to stumble upon the excellent work of Black and Hartl, so I thought I'd share them here even though they are not video.  They are the two highest yield sources that I have personally used for learning Ruby and they are likely to save you time.

hth,

Perry

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions to me Perry. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

There are on [www.tekpub.com](http://www.tekpub.com), but for $$$. You can get monthly subscription for about 30$ I think.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this course http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/ruby-for-newbies/

Answer (score 0):

Also good course [Ruby Essential Training](http://www.lynda.com/tutorial/47905?srchtrk=index:1%0Alinktypeid:2%0Aq%3aRuby%20Essential%20Training%0Apage:1%0As%3arelevance%0Asa%3atrue%0Aproducttypeid:2) but for money

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there are any beginner video tutorials for ruby. If you are a total newbie, I would recommend picking up a copy of Chris Pine's book **Learn to Program** http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/

If you want to learn Rails, Michael Hartl's **Rails Tutorial** http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ is the best resource for any beginner who wants to learn Rails - in my opinion. It takes the reader through everything required to become a decent web-developer. The book is available for free on-line. There are 15 hours of screencasts as well to guide one through the tutorial. At $95, the PDF/screencast bundle is a steal!