# Differences between Ruby 1.8 vs 1.9 in list's element comparison

Tags: ruby, list, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.8

The two Ruby versions are: 1.8.7 (which the school uses) vs. 1.9.3 (current version, that I have on my system).

Just curious on what is different in 1.9.3 that makes the following not work properly. The function outputs `true` if all the elements in the list is the same, `false` if it is not all the same.

```
e.g.
[1,1,1] => true
[1,2,1] => false
```

In Ruby 1.9.4,

```
odd_one_out_in_list?([1,1,1])
=> false  #which is should output 'true'
```

while in Ruby 1.8.7,

```
odd_one_out_in_list?([1,1,1])
=> true  #which is good
```

The logic in the following looks ok to me. What is different in 1.9.4? I have checked out:
    [What is the difference between Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574/what-is-the-difference-between-ruby-1-8-and-ruby-1-9) but I am unable to find the answer there.

Here's my function:

```
def odd_one_out_in_list?(list)
  sorted_list = list.sort
  if sorted_list[0] == sorted_list[list.length-1]
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

Comment: Also, I can't reproduce this. 1.8.7 & 1.9.3 give me the same results for your provided input.

Comment: And why not just return the comparison result?

Comment: Try `def odd_one_out_in_list?(list); list.uniq.size == 1; end`. Is simpler and probably faster.

Answer (score 0):

> Try def odd_one_out_in_list?(list); list.uniq.size == 1; end. Is simpler and probably faster