# Match unicode text with Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, regex, unicode, ruby-1.8.7

I have a regex that is used for matching unicode string and works pretty cool with all versions of Ruby newer than 1.8.7:

```
/[\p{L}\p{Space}]+/u
```

How it can be achieved with Ruby 1.8.7?

Comment: According to this answer [What is the difference between Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21621/626273), Ruby learned Unicode properties in 1.9, so `\p{Space}` should not be working in Ruby < 1.9. Before Posix classes was used like `[:space:]`.

Comment: You mean that it works with Ruby *newer* than 1.8.7, right?  Not *older*?

Comment: Sure, newer :) Sorry for that

Comment: @stema thanks, it works now with Posix classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode properties were added in Ruby with version 1.9, so in older versions you have to use Posix classes like `[:space:]` or `[:alpha:]`

See [POSIX Bracket Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) for more details.