# Tips for ruby migration from 1.8?

Tags: ruby

I am looking at migrating to the new ruby. The question is what is the new ruby? 1.9.3 with some patchlevel or 2.0 with some patchlevel?

Has anyone tried doing the migration? I know a lot of code is not going to be backward compatible but how do you manage production then - keep using old ruby for old code and new ruby for the latest stuff? Kind of hack it in with RVM? But then again will 1.8 code run side by side with say 1.9?

Also if I want to test for the existing code compat levels between 1.8 and 1.9 what would you recommend?

Comment: The new ruby is version 2.x. Why would you think version 1.9.3 is the new ruby?

Comment: We need more information. What OS are you on? How comfortable are you installing languages? Why would RVM be a hack, when it's highly recommended and well tested? Ruby is great at maintaining backwards compatibility. *Rails* updates will be a problem, as will any gems that have upgraded since you last did a `gem update`. It really sounds like you haven't done any prep-work to get ready to upgrade or real research into your question, and, as a result it's wide-open and hard to answer. It's also highly opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

- **What is the new ruby?** — On [ruby-lang.org](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/#news) you'll find that currently Ruby 2.0.0-p274 (and Ruby 1.9.3-p448) are the most recent releases. If you are migrating to a new version, you should always chose the latest patchlevel.
- **Has anyone tried doing the migration?** — Yup. I've been using both [RVM](http://rvm.io) and [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) to manage different Ruby installs and gemsets (they both get the job done). This way, you *can* run different code in production.
- **...test for the existing code compat levels...** — This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21621/766783) (gee... from 2008 :-)) is pretty much comprehensive. If you have code using 1.8-specific behaviour, write an extensive test suite, switch to Ruby 2.0.0 and compare the results.

Btw.: The only problems I had when switching from Ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9.3 were encoding related, some of which could be resolved with a simple `#encoding: UTF-8` comment. Other (I/O-related) code has needed some refactoring, though.

I also had some trouble with the built-in (but switchable) Syck and Psych YAML parsers, which behave a little different when it comes to serializing `BigDecimal` values, but that is caused by a Rails monkey patch (upgrading Rails from 2.3.x to 3.2.x or 4.0.0 is another level of pain :-)).