# Why does this code work in ruby 1.8 and not ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, compatibility, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.8

This piece of code:

```
def func *; end
[func "hello"]
```

is parsed without error in Ruby 1.8.7, but returns a syntax error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting '}'
```

in Ruby >= 1.9. I looked through [What is the difference between Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574/what-is-the-difference-between-ruby-1-8-and-ruby-1-9), but couldn't find a reference to this. Does anyone know what change is causing this?

Comment: just to see - could you try `r = [ func("hello")]` ?

Comment: @Babai no. It is a syntax error: `syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('`. Seems to be a precedence issue, since calling the method with parenthesis works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's to avoid ambiguity. Consider the following:

```
def foo(a, b = 1) # foo takes an optional second argument
end

[foo 1, 2]
```

This could be interpreted as `[(foo 1), 2]` or as `[(foo 1, 2)]`.

There are two references in the [*Calling Methods*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html) docs (although not directly related to the array literal):

> Note that the parenthesis are optional ... Except when there is difference between using and omitting parentheses
>
> In many cases parenthesis are not necessary when sending a message ... However, parenthesis are necessary to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: def foo(a) end; [foo 1] generates the same error in v2.0.0, yet there is no ambiguity here.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the error is raised at the parser level, regardless of the method definition. After all, Ruby is a dynamic language allowing you to change the method at any time.

Comment: In my example, `def foo(a) end`, I noticed `[foo 1]` and `[foo (1)]` both produce errors, but `[foo(1)]` is OK.  I know it is good practice to avoid spaces between a method name and the opening parenthesis, but they are permitted in some cases, though it seems a bit vague as to where they are permitted.  In any event, I assume `[foo 1]` is treated as `[foo (1)]` in this regard, so maybe that's what the parser is looking at.