# Compass, bootstrap-sass and ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, compass-sass

after I finally managed to get Compass running on my hosted web space (no root access), there is a new problem when trying to install bootstrap-sass:

```
$ compass watch
LoadError on line 31 of /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb: no such file to load -- bootstrap-sass

gem install bootstrap-sass
ERROR:  Error installing bootstrap-sass:
        execjs requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
```

Well, it is quite obvious what's going on: I need Ruby >= 1.9.3 while the server only offers 1.8.7. I already checked: It is not possible to use another ruby version on this server.

Is there any way/hack/solution to use bootstrap-sass?

Comment: `1.8.7` was released in 2008, was supported until 2012 and since 2013 there are [no security updates anymore](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/). Btw even support for `1.9.3` [has ended months ago](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/02/23/support-for-ruby-1-9-3-has-ended/). If your hoster does not support newer versions of Ruby, then you should run and find another hoster...

Comment: This is absolutely correct. But right know I need a solution that could work under these given circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally agree that still using Ruby 1.8.7 is not a good idea. I am not sure why my hoster still uses a version this old, but it is simply a fact I cannot change. Sure, I can move to another hoster but for now I was able to find a working solution. Maybe someone else has the same problem. So this worked for me:

`gem install bootstrap-sass` did not work because it requires `execjs` and the latest version requires Ruby > 1.9.3. **Gladly `bootstrap-sass` does NOT require the latest version of `execjs`**. So the solution is simple: Install a previous version of `execjs` which is happy with ruby 1.8.7:

```
gem install execjs -v 2.5.0
gem install bootstrap-sass
```

Answer (score 1):

When a gem depends on a specific (or newer) version of Ruby, then the reason is usually that the gem depends or uses a feature that did not exist in older versions.

There are many [differences between Ruby `1.8.7` and `1.9.3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21621/2483313): The new hash syntax, better UTF8 support and new methods or methods with changed behavior - just to name a few.

When a gem was build for `1.9.3` and you want to use tat gem with an older version, there is IMHO only on option: Fork that gem, review the source code and rewrite everything that is not compatible with `1.8.7`.

You will very likely learn that such gems depend on other gems that also depend on more up-to-date versions of Ruby. Do the same for that gems...